# footbar is not at completely at the bottom, but only on homepage

Tags: css

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the footer is just slightly elevated from the bottom of the screen, but this only appears on the home page. Every other page in the site the footer appears to be completely on the bottom. What can be the issue here?

```
.footbar {
    background-color: #181818;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Simply HTML (in HAML)

```
%body
    ....
    .footer
```

Comment: Give `bottom: 0`. Also post the relevant html code.

Comment: Other pages are the same. You just have more content so it looks like it is stuck at the bottom. Take some content out and see if footer stays on the bottom on other pages. [good read here](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page)

Comment: what might be the issue if I assign bottom: 0 and the footer move up even more? @ODelibalta it appears that the footer is only slight raised if I am using 100% of my browser height. If I reduce the browser height the footer reduce to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
.footbar {
background-color: #181818;
height: 50px;
bottom:0px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
overflow: hidden;
}
```